# JSContext Release

Tags: ios, objective-c, javascriptcore

This is my code:

```
JSContext *context = [_webView valueForKeyPath:@"documentView.webView.mainFrame.javaScriptContext"];

[context setExceptionHandler:^(JSContext *ctx, JSValue *value) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", value);
}];

JSObject *obj = [[JSObject alloc] init];
context[@"iOS"] = obj;
```

The above `JSObject` was not released. Do you have any way?

Answer (score -2):

JSObject *obj = [[[JSObject alloc] init] autorelease];

Comment: ARC environment